# Use value to another function in any function

Tags: python-2.7

```
def anshu():
    
  a=1+2
  print(a)


anshu()

def sanju():
    b=2+3
    print(b)

sanju()

def bala():
    
     
    c=a+b
    print(c)
```

can you explain?
I gave many value in one or more function i want use these value in any function in python

Comment: What exactly is it you want explained?

Comment: If the function returns a value instead of printing it, you can use the returned value where you call the function. But maybe you are asking something else?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access a variable from one function in another function, you can either return the variable from the first function and pass it as an argument to the second function, or you can make the variable global so that it can be accessed from any function. Here's an example using the first approach:

```
def anshu():
    a = 1 + 2
    return a

def sanju():
    b = 2 + 3
    return b

def bala(a, b):
    c = a + b
    print(c)

anshu_result = anshu()
sanju_result = sanju()
bala(anshu_result, sanju_result)
```

Here's an example using the second approach:

```
def anshu():
    global a
    a = 1 + 2

def sanju():
    global b
    b = 2 + 3

def bala():
    c = a + b
    print(c)

anshu()
sanju()
bala()
```

Note that using global variables is generally not considered good practice, because it can make your code difficult to maintain and debug. It's usually better to use the first approach of passing variables as arguments to functions.

Comment: Very very thank you so much